# ListContourPlot from three matrices

Tags: plotting

I have 3 matrices, each of size $101 \times 101$.

```
List6 = Table[{x1[[i, j]]}, {i, 101}, {j, 101}]
List7 = Table[{y1[[i, j]]}, {i, 101}, {j, 101}]
List8 = Table[{xDisp1[[i, j]]}, {i, 101}, {j, 101}]
```

and I want to use `ListContourPlot`

```
ListContourPlot[{{x1[[1,1],y1[[1,1]],xDisp[[1,1]]},{x1[[1,2],y1[[1,2]],xDisp[[1,2]]},....}]
```

How could I use `ListContourPlot` from the three lists using the sequence I have given above ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it makes much sense to create a `ListContourPlot` with two or more separate lists.  What do you think it should look like?  How will you display three different values at a given location?

I'd use `ListPlot3D` to keep the data sets visible:

```
list1 = Table[RandomReal[], {20}, {20}];
list2 = Table[.5 + .3 RandomReal[], {20}, {20}];
list3 = Table[1 + .2 RandomReal[], {20}, {20}];

ListPlot3D[{list1, list2, list3},
 InterpolationOrder -> 0,
 PlotStyle -> {{Opacity[0.5], Blue}, 
               {Opacity[0.5], Yellow}, 
               {Opacity[0.5], Red}}]
```

Comment: I just want to learn how could I manipulate my lists to be suitable for listcontourplot function ? Then i will compare it with an another study given in contourplot

Comment: Manipulating lists is not the problem or issue.  You haven't specified what you want your graph to look like, so it is impossible to answer your question.  Why not simply print three separate contour plots, side-by-side?

Answer (score 0):

Use your own matrices `x1`, `y1` and `xDisp1` in place of the random ones below:

```
m = 30;
x1 = RandomReal[1, {m, m}];
y1 = RandomReal[1, {m, m}];
xDisp1 = RandomReal[10, {m, m}];

data = Join @@ 
   Table[{x1[[i, j]], y1[[i, j]], xDisp1[[i, j]]}, {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, m}];
(* or  data = Join @@ (Transpose /@ Transpose[{x1, y1, xDisp1}]) *)

ListContourPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

If you need to work with `list6`, `list7` and `list8`

```
list6 = Table[{x1[[i, j]]}, {i, m}, {j, m}];
list7 = Table[{y1[[i, j]]}, {i, m}, {j, m}];
list8 = Table[{xDisp1[[i, j]]}, {i, m}, {j, m}];
```

you can use

```
data2 = Join @@ 
   Table[{list6[[i, j, 1]], list7[[i, j, 1]], list8[[i, j, 1]]}, {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, m}];
data == data2
```

> True

Alternatively, use

```
data2 = Join @@ (Transpose /@ 
    Transpose[{list6[[All, All, 1]], list7[[All, All, 1]], list8[[All, All, 1]]}])
```